# Listing all users on client with meteor

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

According the the meteor documentation, all users should be published to all clients if the autopublish package is installed.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users

I have the autopublish package installed, but using `forEach` on `Meteor.users` only lists the currently logged in user.

Is there a more correct way to list all the users on the client by using coffeescript?

Comment: is this a bug in the docs? there is a related closed issue https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/517

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you auto publish users collection without use subscribe

```
if Meteor.isServer

    Meteor.publish null, ->
        Meteor.users.find {},
            fields:
                username: 1
                profile: 1
```

if you want to subscribe specify users you can

```
if Meteor.isServer

    Meteor.publish 'users-by-selector', (options) ->
        Meteor.users.find options, # options as selector like $in: name: 'john'
            fields: # use fields to only publish specify fields you want to send. 
                username: 1
                profile: 1

if Meteor.isClient

    Meteor.autosubscribe ->
        options = Session.get 'your mongodb selector'
        Meteor.subscribe 'users-by-selector', options, ->
            console.log 'on Subscribe Complete Callback.'
            if Meteor.users.find().count()
                Session.set 'specifyUsersLoaded', true
```

Comment: Your first snippet works, though I had to add ``emails: 1`` under ``fields:``, as both ``username`` and ``profile`` are empty for all the users. Apparently a user isn't autopublished unless there is a value in its autopublished fields.

Comment: I did not find the limitation mentioned by @danielsvane. One thing to pay attention to, though, is that different provider packages provide different data structures. This makes sense when you think about it, but it can be confusing if you aren't ready for it. @crapthings' code above (including `profile` and `username`) would work well to get usernames for both Facebook and the `accounts-password` packages. To get the user name from a `user` record, you would need `user.username || user.profile.name`.

Comment: Great and helpful answer +1, but -1 for assuming CoffeeScript. Question is not tagged as CoffeeScript. It's not called Meteor.coffee

Comment: @rdickert They might have fixed that little hurdle, as this question is kinda old.

Comment: @BjornTipling I was using CoffeeScript though, so his answer was spot on.

Comment: @danielsvane Where exactly did you use CoffeeScript in your question?

Comment: @danielsvane Questions-Answers in SO are for everybody. So if your question is not Coffeescript, we are not waiting for it :)  (I'm saying this drinking coffee... sad world)

Comment: Could someone post a non Coffeescript version of the answer?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an excerpt from Meteor's [Parties example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/other/parties):

```
// in server.js
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});

// in client.js
Meteor.subscribe("directory");
```

Comment: The example isn't there anymore, how can I iterate each user in a template?

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/other/parties (code is the same, updated link)